# Add Section and Row to UITableView to Reset Table

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, reset

I have a UITableView that the user can build and add rows to it.

When the Table View is being edited I would like to add a section with a single, red row to reset the the table

My Navigation Bar is busy enough with real estate using UIBarButtonItems to toggle edit, add, and segue the view.

I imagine I'll need to do something to "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and "NumberofSectionsInTableView"

Any help on how to accomplish this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

its quite like you wrote and it is not that hard to do.

Catch the event of the edit-button in your navigationBar and execute a method where you set the number of your sections and cells. Add to the number of sections + 1 (for your delete section) and to the number of your cells +1 for the cell in the section (because you need a cell - a section without cell is nothing).

if you now call [yourtableview reloadData] numberOfCellsInTableView and all the other delegate methods automatically get called and your new cell+section is visible.

To make this cell custom (red button), call cellForRowAtIndexPath and declare your custom cell for this row.

Good luck.